# filtering out elements from an array based on second array in javascript

Tags: arrays, filtering

I have two following arrays

```
1) ['data/proxies/AuthDecoder/1/AuthDecoder.zip',
  'data/proxies/JSONP/1/JSONP.zip',
  'data/proxies/XMLP/1/XMLP.zip',
  'data/proxies/accessControl/1/accessControl.zip']

2) ['AuthDecoder', 'JSONP', 'XMLP',]
```

how do I filter out the first array so that the first array only contains those elements that also have a match in second array.
The name of the proxy (with .zip extension) should match in both arrays.

So after the filtering, first array should look like

```
['data/proxies/AuthDecoder/1/AuthDecoder.zip',
  'data/proxies/JSONP/1/JSONP.zip',
  'data/proxies/XMLP/1/XMLP.zip',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex for the same

```
var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain"; 
var res = str.match(/Spain/i);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
```

write string to be matched between '/' and then followed by modifier

1. i is case insensitive
2. g is global search
3. m is used in multi-line search

Comment: this will just give me the name of the proxy not the whole path (i need full path), and i will have repeated element in the second array and repeated element(with just different number) in the first array, so those two repeated elements will match two times for the same path in the first array.